# How to manage and communicate with multiple IPython/Jupyter kernels from a Python script?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to mimic the functionality of a notebook server, and instead coordinate the creation/management of different IPython/Jupyter kernels from a central body of logic (i.e. my own Python script).

For example, I want to:

- Define an abstract command e.g. "add(x, y)"
- Communicate the abstract command to multiple kernels e.g. an IPython kernel and Scala kernel
- Have each kernel execute the command however they wish
- Return the result from each kernel to the central body of logic

Can anyone point me in the direction of how to programmatically start/stop/communicate with multiple IPython/Jupyter kernels?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A KernelManager deals with starting and stopping a single kernel, and there's a MultiKernelManager to co-ordinate more than one.

- http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.kernel.manager.html
- http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.kernel.multikernelmanager.html

Then you can use the `.client()` method to get a KernelClient instance which handles communications with a kernel:

- http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.kernel.client.html

For details of how you communicate with a kernel, see the [message spec docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/development/messaging.html). Some of this is abstracted away by KernelClient, but you'll probably need to know some of it.

Comment: Can you update this answer for the newer versions? Also, can one interact with "native kernels" like IJulia via Python, too?

Comment: The relevant APIs moved to the [jupyter_client package](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/index.html), but otherwise are still fairly similar. They work for Jupyter kernels in any language.