# Weird JSON-like python console output

Tags: python, json, console, output

I'm getting this weird text before the actual console output. How can I get rid of it?

Code:

```
print('hi!')
```

Output:

```
{"date":"2024-03-15T10:54:43.844Z","msg_id":"ecd3d443-dd77-45f5-9687-d154abad9344","msg_type":"execute_request","session":"a77e8270-27d7-491d-9fa8-1d0407a3f5f2","username":"6aa1144b-bdeb-4e46-9ba0-0c8337f75c7e","version":"5.2"}
{}
{"cellId":"vscode-notebook-cell:some\path"}
{"silent":false,"store_history":true,"user_expressions":{},"allow_stdin":true,"stop_on_error":false,"code":"print('hi!')"}
hi!
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222141/getting-output-from-jupyter-kernel-in-ipython-script) is the closest result I got from the internet.

Comment: Weird question too

Comment: @Wonka, thank you for your feedback. How do you think I can improve my question?

Comment: @alexfrigo Please read up on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I think the issue is likely with your environment, unless there's more code not included.