# Interacting with Jupyter notebook or kernel programmatically

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a Jupyter notebook server running inside a Docker container on some cluster and I run some scala code (with Spark) in a bunch of these notebooks. They show up externally at some URL (`http://blah.com:11111/tree`). I need to automate this by writing a python script that can run notebooks from anywhere: open URL, run it, shutdown and restart kernels if needed, etc. There is some mentioning on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847440/starting-jupyter-notebook-programmatically-from-another-notebook) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949881/how-to-manage-and-communicate-with-multiple-ipython-jupyter-kernels-from-a-pytho), but it would be good to have a complete example: open HTTP request to notebook server in Python, interact with it, close it. The [nbconvert](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html) approach wouldn't work in this case (assume no access to Jupyter server). The [jupyter kernel_gateway](https://github.com/jupyter/kernel_gateway) sounds interesting but I couldn't find a good example which shows how to open HTTP request to notebook server in Python, interact with it, close it. There are some interesting information [jupyter-client messaging](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/messaging.html) and [RESTful API](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-Notebook-Server-API), but again I couldn't find an example that I'm looking for. Thank you.

One way to do this is to create a notebook and put the following code in it:

```
import nbformat, os
from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor

print os.getcwd()

with open('./my_notebook.ipynb') as f:
  nb = nbformat.read(f, as_version=4)

ep = ExecutePreprocessor(timeout=30, kernel_name='python2')
ep.preprocess(nb, {'metadata': {'path': './'}})

with open('./my_notebook.ipynb', 'wt') as f:
  nbformat.write(nb, f)
```

This code can be a base for further automation: reading `my_notebook.ipynb` as a json file, changing the code and cells in it, storing it back and re-running it again. All kinds of loops and branches and multi-processing can be developed based on this. However, this doesn't work for spylon-kernel and scala/Spark notebooks. When I do `kernel_name='spylon-kernel'` it gives me exception `NoSuchKernel: No such kernel named spylon-kernel`

I think the solution should come from [jupyter-client](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), but I couldn't find a good example.

Comment: you might want to use Selenium to do this as if you were a user.

Comment: Have you considered exporting notebook code (with nbconvert via ssh), compiling to a jar and running by spark-submit?

Comment: Please see some edits